# ember.js use value from model instance in template

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js

I want to use the value from my model instance in my template, in PHP I would go by doing the following:

```
<?php
class User {
    private $name;
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$localuser = new User("john doe");
?>

<p>My name is: <?= $localuser->getName(); ?></p>
```

But how do I do this in Ember.js? Or am I misunderstanding the MVC model from Ember.js?

This is my Ember.js code for creating the localuser instance:

```
Example = Ember.Application.create();
Example.User = Example.Object.extend({
    firstname: null,
    lastname: null,
    network: null,

    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstName') + " " + this.get('lastName');
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')

});

Example.LocalUser = Example.User.create({
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe"
});

Example.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller) {
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
      this.render("exampleTemplate");
  }
});

and my HTML template (which doesn't work):

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="exampleTemplate">
{{#model Example.LocalUser}}
    {{fullName}}
{{/model}}
</script>
```

What do I need to put in my template to get the fullname value from Example.LocalUser to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do almost exactly the same as in PHP: create an *instance* of an object. You're almost right, with some errors:

1. Although you're indeed creating an instance by saying `Example.LocalUser = Example.User.create({...})`, this is an anti-pattern in Ember. The convention is to keep *classes* on the application namespace, like `Example.IndexRoute`, `Example.User`, etc. But never *instances*. Model objects are instances, and the best way to expose them to the view is by setting up a controller using the `model` or `setupController` hooks.
2. As far as I know, there is no `{{#model}}...{{/model}}` Handlebars helper. You can use the variables provided by the controller: `{{model}}` or just `{{controller}}`, if you set it up eg. in the controller's route.
3. You have typos in your example: `firstname` -> `firstName` :)

Given by the above, the (presumably) working example should be something like:

**JavaScript:**

```
Example = Ember.Application.create();

Example.User = Ember.Object.extend({
  firstName: null,
  lastName: null,
  network: null,

  fullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + " " + this.get('lastName');
  }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});


Example.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var user = Example.User.create({
      firstName: "John",
      lastName: "Doe"
    });

    return user;
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render("exampleTemplate");
  }
});
```

**Template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="exampleTemplate">
  {{model.fullName}} - {{controller.fullName}}
</script>
```

**Output:**

John Doe - John Doe

Comment: but what if I want to create multiple instances of the Model user, for lets say a chat application?

Comment: Then you return an *array of instances* from the `model` hook, and you iterate through them using the `{{#each}}` Handlebars helper in your template.